# Evenly spaced out row of buttons required

Tags: android, xml

Using 3 rows and 4 columns I have tried to evenly space out all the buttons horizontally but have failed. vertically is fine.

Below are 3 different attempts to space out the buttons, 1 for each of my 3 rows. The first row stretches the graphic (which is unwanted), the second row does not stretch but there is no spacing (spacing between the graphics is required), while the third stretches without any spacing. Please help me to evenly space these out. Other peoples solutions on this same site have not worked. Should I try using a table instead?

Visual summary= without stretching the graphic:
I want  | x x x x |
and not |   xxxx  |

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/clear64" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/clear64" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/clear64" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/clear64" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktilesml"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clear64" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am not gettting what exectly you say discribe simple way.

Comment: Try [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

Comment: ps GridLayout is API 14 or latter, I want something that will work from API 7 or 8.

Comment: Hi can you upload the image of desired output?

Comment: Have you tried using a LinearLayout with Buttons that are padded and all weighted 1?

Comment: To Phobos: padding is not dynamic and so wont pad appropriately for different sized (and shaped) devices. That is what I need. Gridview is nice but if the phones screen is small it scrolls off the screen and I want all of them on.

Comment: To Nimish: similar examples can be found at - https://lh3.ggpht.com/51m8GmXfOat7HzPlo9Y_SvX0qebQe3q62qgTN7KuBWQb-zVIYtPoYEIP-tnV3Fv7w2g=h230 and https://lh4.ggpht.com/xn7bAAz3fAqYwbHTEyAjlJTHhbDQ5gnOhx47BX853xY-bKwmkSKLHuDKHM-xaVQ6nA=h230

Comment: Why not just put a margin on each button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

try this for your first row. Similarly can be done for all the row,

So unless you don't want the images to be stretched you need to rap them in a layout. Doing so you will manage the spacing and the drawable will look just fine. If you stretch the buttons then the drawable will also be stretched accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did with a calculator project I was working on.  Requiring buttons in rows all the same size.  You will need to add padding to your buttons to suit your needs.:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/NumberPad">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/NumberRow123"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed8"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed9"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed6"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/NumberRow789">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/unpressed3"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This only a partial pull from my layout.  The display and other features were not related to your answer.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This type of thing will have to do with my adding some spacing but it's not what I wanted, as I don't want the stretching. Can I dynamically change the spacing or do I need multiple XMLs for different size screens?

Comment: Developer guide suggest that best practice should include 4 layouts, if your app is going to support that size screen, ldpi (small), mdpi (medium), hdpi(large) and xhdpi (big).  Each layout covers a cross section of screen sizes and densities.  So providing an hdpi layout will most likely fit any modern smartphone, while xhdpi will span most tablet screen ranges.  Check out this page that explains it better than I can.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks Phobos, I am aware of that too.

Comment: Is there a reason the third button has `match_parent`? Android also displays a message for `android:layout_weight="1"`: `Nested weights are bad for performance`